# Codeigniter Extend Form_validation not work with callback function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I cannot run a callback function if I put in the MY_Form_validation file...

I have it running for now.

My controllers :

```html
function article_new()
{   
    //Variable de configuration
    $allowed_types = 'jpg|jpeg|png';
    $max_size     ='2048000';// 2 Mo
    $max_filename  = '';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('image','Image','callback_handle_upload['.$allowed_types.','.$max_size.','.$max_filename.']');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      --CODE--
```

My callback function in the same controllers :

```html
function handle_upload($image,$param)
{       
    if(isset($_FILES['image']) && !empty($_FILES['image']['name']))
    {
        // PARAMETRE
        $file = $_FILES['image'];
        $filename = $file['name'];
        $param = preg_split('/,/', $param);

        $allowed_types = $param[0];
        $max_size = $param[1];
        $max_filename = $param[2];

        $validType = false;
        $validWeight = false;
        $validLongName = false;

        // LONGUEUR NOM IMAGE
        if(!empty($max_filename)){
            if(strlen($filename) > $max_filename)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', 'Le nom de l\'image ne doit pas depasser '.$max_filename.' caracteres');
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $validLongName = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $validLongName = true;
        }

        // EXTENSION VALIDE OU PAS 
        $extension = end((explode(".",$filename)));
        $extension_config = array_map('trim',explode(" ",$allowed_types));
        if(!empty($allowed_types)){
            if(in_array($extension, $extension_config)){
                $validType = true;
            }
            else{
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', "Ce type de fichier n'est pas autorisé");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else{
            $validType = true;
        }

        // POIDS VALID OU PAS
        if(!empty($max_size)){
            if($file['size'] > $max_size)
            {
                $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', "L'image est trop lourde 2 Mo maximum");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {   
                $validWeight = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            $validWeight = true;
        }

        if($validLongName == true && $validType == true && $validWeight == true)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $exist_cover = $this->blog_model->get_cover();
        if($exist_cover == NULL){
            // throw an error because nothing was uploaded
            $this->form_validation->set_message('handle_upload', "Vous devez uploader une image");
            return false;
        }
        else{
            // Il existe une image dans bdd donc je fais un edit donc pas obliger de poste une image
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

But if I want to put my callback fonction in the MY_Form_validation file, it doesn't work...
I do this in my controllers for my article_new function (remove callback) :

```html
$this->form_validation->set_rules('image','Image','handle_upload['.$allowed_types.','.$max_size.','.$max_filename.']')
```

My MY_Form_validation file :

```html
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation{

    function __construct($config = array()){
          parent::__construct($config);
     }


    function handle_upload ...
```

Answer (score 0):

if u extend Form_validation with your own function handle_upload then u no need to write "callback_" - just handle_upload

for using callback_your_method u need write method in controller "your_method"

Or better write method with underscore like _handle_upload, so in validation rules it will be "callback__handle_upload" - this way method will not be accessed from browser directly

Good luck!:)

P.S. MY_Form_validation class must be in libraries